# How to get correct value or index on x-axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, charts

I have data that looks like this.

```
    Year  Quarter  Quantity  Price
0   2000        1        23    142
1   2000        2        23    144
2   2000        3        23    147
3   2000        4        23    151
4   2001        1        22    160
5   2001        2        22    183
6   2001        3        22    186
7   2001        4        22    186
8   2002        1        21    212
9   2002        2        19    232
10  2002        3        19    223
```

I am trying to get the years on the x-axis, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do that.  Here is my sample code.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Year']).agg({'Quantity':'sum','Price':'sum'}).reset_index()
price = df1.Price
mean_x = pd.Series(df1.Price).rolling(window=4).mean()


# plot price of policies sold per year along with moving average of same
plt.title('Price of Policies Sold Over Time')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Policies')
plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
plt.plot(df1.Year.values, price, label='Policy Prices')
plt.plot(df1.Year.values, mean_x, label='Policy Prices')
plt.plot(mean_x, label='Moving Average of Policy Prices')
plt.show()
```

Here is the result.

[image]

So, on the x-axis, I want to display the years.  How can I display the year values?

Comment: Just passing the years as x axis when you plot should work. plt.plot(df.Year.values, df.Price.values, label='Policy Prices')

Comment: I updated my post with your suggestion.  There is still something very much off here.  Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You have one plot (Moving Average of Policy Prices) that's called with just the mean prices, so mathplotlib assumes that the corresponding x axis starts from 0 and extends to the length of your data. Pass years and values to all your plots

Comment: I just tried that.  It's still doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: Try removing plt.plot(mean_x, label='Moving Average of Policy Prices')

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working.  My solution is shown below.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Year']).agg({'Quantity':'sum','Price':'sum'}).reset_index()
price = df1.Price

# moving average below
mean_x = pd.Series(df1.Price).rolling(window=4).mean()

# plot price of policies sold per year along with moving average of same
plt.title('Price of Policies Sold Over Time')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Policies')
plt.plot(df1.Year, df1.Price, label='Policy Prices')
plt.plot(df1.Year, mean_x, label='Moving Average Prices')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]